# Installed PHP 7.3 on Mac, but it's still rendering 7.1.23

Tags: php

My team is upgrading to PHP 7.3. Currently I am on 7.1.23. I'm having a heck of a time getting PHP to use the new version. When I log out `PHP info`, it's 7.1.23. I've installed the new version with this line and it says it's successful ( tried it a few times).

`curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3`

When I do `which php` in the command line, it gives me `/usr/bin/php`. Is there something I need to do/try? My `httpd.conf` file seems correct as well with this line

`LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`

Just been trying to figure this out all day and I can't seem to :). Thanks. Also I am running Mac OS High Sierra

Comment: I had this issue some days prior and the only thing that worked for me is to locate the current php in the command line and uninstall it by deleting it manually then installing php with brew again

Comment: what's the output of `php -v` ?

Comment: Did you go through all the steps in [this link](https://jasonmccreary.me/articles/upgrade-php-mac-os-x/)?

Comment: @rob PHP 7.1.23 (cli)

Comment: @BramVerstraten thanks, I ended up deleting the LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so line and it loaded the new version. Only took me all day, hahaha

Comment: I am having same issue. In the terminal it is showing 7.4 but in the phpinfo() it is showing 7.3. How to change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `which php` you get

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Open finder, goto the “go” tab and select the second from the bottom option which says “Go to folder”

This will open a input, type `/usr/bin/php` inside and you’ll be redirected to that folder. Delete all the php files manually from there.

Now in the terminal, do

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

This just installs homebrew which will make this very very easy
Then do

```
$ brew install php73
```

---

EDIT: For new versions of PHP the command is

```
brew install php@8.0
```

Make sure to check which version you want to use before installing

Comment: in the future, how does homebrew plan to differentiate between php version 7.3.0 and php version 73.0.0?

Comment: @hanshenrik `brew install php 730` you can try it now if you are from the future

Comment: for new versions of php and brew, the command is `brew install php@8.0` This might answer hanshenrik question as well.